# location updates from iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator

i am testing my application on XCode 4 using iPhone simulator.

i have made program which will take location updates using G.P.S. on my MAC there is no G.P.S only internet working. So how can i check my application is working or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The guys from [future tap](http://www.futuretap.com/blog/simulating-core-location/) created  [FTLocationSimulator](https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator) for this task.

It is a replacement class for CLLocationManager and it allows the replay of tracks recorded in kml format.

Works very well.

---

I heard that there is a built-in location simulator in the iPhone Simulator of iOS5. But I've never used it.

Comment: so with CLLocationManager this is not possible? i have just internet working on my MAC not GPS.

Comment: CLLocationManager on the simulator should return the position of your mac (if known and enabled) or the position of Apple HQ when you ask it for a location.

Comment: simulator should return the position of mac using internet only? because i don't have GPS on my mac